# add table index before SELECT WHERE and drop them before INSERT

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Is it considered a best practice or an overall performance boost for MySQL if I add an index to my table before `SELECT..WHERE` statements and drop them before `INSERT` statements?

Comment: You must be kidding!!! When you create an index for a table that has already data, the database software scans the whole table to actually build the index. So, how would you answer your own question?

Comment: In general you would not do this but indexes have an insert performance hit as well so if you are doing really big(whatever that means) bulk inserts when no selects are expected then dropping the indexes and recreating them might give you a throughput boost for the inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the answer is obvious: Adding an index to a table before `SELECT ... WHERE` statements and dropping them before `INSERT` statements is **really bad** practice. And I'm pretty sure this holds true for every database.

You would have the overhead of creating an index entry for every row of the table on each `SELECT`. That's far more costly than creating/updating an index entry once when a new row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer